# Multi-site setup in Craft3

Tags: craft3, multi-site

Hi guys are the any more detailed tutorials on how to setup a multi site on Craft3 BETA? I created two sites now, a Danish and English through the admin (Settings → Sites). The domain is the same but the Danish version will have the path `http://localhost:8888/dk` whereas the English version will be everything that does not have the first path of `/dk`.

I have set in the `general.php` the following:

```php
return [
    '*' => [
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
        'usePathInfo' => true,
        'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true
    ],
   'SITEHANDLE_NAME_ENGLISH' => [
       'siteUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/
   ],
   'SITEHANDLE_NAME_DANISH’ => [
       'siteUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/dk'
   ],
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',
    'devMode' => false,
];
```

In the Danish folder `/dk`, I created a new `index.php`, and the site correctly direct to this file from the URL, BUT, it does not change the site to the the Danish site, even though I have defined my `index.php` with the new php constant:

```php
<?php
// Project root path
$root = dirname('../');
define('CRAFT_SITE', "SITEHANDLE_NAME_DANISH");
// Composer autoloader
require_once '../craft_folder/vendor/autoload.php';

// dotenv?
if (file_exists("../craft_folder/.env")) {
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv("../craft_folder/");
    $dotenv->load();   
}

// Craft
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', "../craft_folder/");

$app = require '../craft_folder/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';

$app->run();
```

How do I tell Craft to load the Danish site from the `index.php`? Right now it will only load the primary site not matter what I try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you watched the Craft Hangout?

[Managing Multiple Sites in Craft 3 – Sites and Localization](https://straightupcraft.com/events/managing-multiple-sites-in-craft-3-sites-and-localization)

Might be of use if you haven't. You'll need about an hour free to view it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check out the free video on it here: [Using Craft CMS 3 Multi-site](https://mijingo.com/lessons/craft-3-multi-site/)

Multi-site has changed as of Craft 3 RC11. It now requires much less config outside of the control panel. [See the official docs on Sites in Craft 3.](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just set up a Norwegian (default) / English multi-site myself, without touching a single config file or adding files/directories (apart from the actual translation-file containing strings in different languages) to the project.

- In the backend, I added the sites Norwegian with path `@web` (and saying that it is the main site) and English with path `@web/en`
- Then I configured my sections and fields to my liking, i.e. determining which ones should support localization

And that was it - I see Norwegian content when accessing http://site.test and English content when accessing http://site.test/en